# Purpose of doing yield return for each item of a enumerable

Tags: c#, foreach, yield

Are the following C# functions equivalent?

```
    protected IEnumerable<TResult> Execute(DbCommand command)
    {
        IDataReader reader = database.ExecuteReader(command);

        foreach (TResult result in resultSetMapper.MapSet(reader))
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }

    protected IEnumerable<TResult> Execute2(DbCommand command)
    {
        IDataReader reader = database.ExecuteReader(command);

        return resultSetMapper.MapSet(reader);
    }
```

I found the first function browsing the code of [Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.CommandAccessor](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/Microsoft-Enterprise-Library/5.0---Beta2/Release/All/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data/CommandAccessor.cs).

If I understand yield return correctly, the foreach has no purpose. If MapSet returns a deferred collection, it can be returned directly. If MapSet returns a materialized collection, there is no profit in returning its elements one by one.

Comment: `yield` returns one item at a time, you may stop iteration and the remaining items will never be generated.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova That is true for the non `yeld` version of the example code too however.

Comment: a simple `MSDN C# Yield` - google search could have answered this for you. why are people not using free tools such as google

Comment: @MethodMan The exact differences between these two methods are actually somewhat subtle and confusing.  They're not the same, but the ways in which they're different are not easy to observe or understand.  While they do follow from the basic documentation on iterator blocks, the implications aren't all obvious.

Comment: I can totally see / understand what you are saying @Servy good point..

Comment: Thanks, I think I can see it now. I was thinking about MapSet, but the difference is that in the first function ExecuteReader will not be called until the collection is enumerated.